# Copy and paste specific columns of data from an existing csv into a new csv file using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file named pollution.csv that is stored in C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi. Therefore, the path to my file is C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\pollution.csv. Now, I want to copy specific columns of data from this file and paste them in another new .csv file named selected.csv in C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi using Python 2. selected.csv is an empty .csv file. I want to select the data using the column headers (i.e. Date (LT), Hour, AQI, Raw Conc.). How do I achieve this simple task? The code that I have tried running so far is typed below:

```
import pandas as pd
pollution = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\air_pollution_new_delhi_2016\pollution.csv")
newColumn1 = pollution['Date']
newColumn2 = pollution['Hour']
newColumn3 = pollution['AQI']
newColumn4 = pollution['Raw Conc.']
```

Comment: `pollution[['Date']].to_csv()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Could you elaborate please? X = pollution[['Date']].to_csv(). What should be X? Should it be my new csv file named newFile.csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols = ['Date','Hour','AQI','Raw Conc.']

filename = r"C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\air_pollution_new_delhi_2016\pollution.csv"

pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=cols).to_csv(r'/path/to/new/file.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am typing the final code that worked below. I want to thank MaxU without whose help this would not have been possible.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Date (LT)','Hour','AQI','Raw Conc.']
pollution = r"C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\pollution.csv"
pd.read_csv(pollution, usecols=cols).to_csv(r"C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\selected.csv", index=False)
```